# How to define a Vec in Rust to support containing multiple types of structs that implement a same trait?

Tags: rust, traits

In c++, I can define a parent class, and the type in vector can just be the father class type. So how to implement that in Rust?

Like for this example:

I defined two types of Integer who both implement the trait Object, now I want to put them in a same vector, is there any way to achieve that?

```rust
pub trait Object<T: Object<T>+Clone> {
    fn sub(&self, x: &T) -> T {
        x.clone() //this is a useless implementation, just for structs don't need to implement this method.
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Integer {
    val: i32
}

impl Integer {
    pub fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        self.val
    }

    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        Integer {
            val
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Int {
    val: i32
}

impl Int {
    pub fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        self.val
    }

    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        Int {
            val
        }
    }
}

impl Object<Int> for Int {
    fn sub(&self, rhs: &Int) -> Int {
        Int {
            val: self.val - rhs.get()
        }
    }
}


impl Object<Integer> for Integer {
    fn sub(&self, rhs: &Integer) -> Integer {
        Integer {
            val: self.val - rhs.get()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn Object>> = Vec::new();
    v.push(Box::new(Integer::new(1)));
    v.push(Box::new(Int::new(2)));
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want a `Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>`.

Comment: could you explain it?

Comment: `Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>` is the actual type you need to use, with `Trait` replaced with the actual name of your trait - see [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) for a tutorial-style explanation. If you show your current code, we can help you adapt it.

Comment: I just added an example, could you fix it?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile even without the `main()` - the compiler complains that `Item` is not a member of the trait `Object`. Please fix your traits, or explain what is your actual goal, so we can help you achieve it.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to delete the `Item` line, you can just ignore it. I just want to put `Int` instances and `Integer` instances in a same vector. The code doesn't compile because I still don't fix this problem.

Comment: Now I delete the `Item` line, but the code still won't compile because I don't specify the type of T in `Object<T>` when I define the vector.

Comment: But if I did that, specify `Vec<Object<Int>>`, I can only put the instances that implement `Object<Int>`, but that is not what I want.

Comment: If you want, I can write you an equal c++ code so you can know my goal.

Comment: why do you parametrize the trait?

Comment: **I want to put different types of struct who all implement a same trait into a same vector** You said I can use Box<dyn Object>,  but I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c129a3aa654a13bdd7ede15203656e96) and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: I see, it seems like I didn't quite understand the `dyn` keyword before. Thanks very very much.

Answer (score 2):

There are several aspects of your design that don't fit in Rust:

- `trait Object<T: Object<T>+Clone>` doesn't help - Rust doesn't do [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), just use `Self` instead.
- for `Object` to be [object-safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) (necessary to put it in a vector), it can't be parameterized by type. A type parameter means you get a completely separate trait for each type.
- `Object::sub()` can't return the result by value, because the size of the value can differ for different implementations, so it wouldn't be object-safe. It must return `Box<dyn Object>` instead.

The code modified as indicated looks like this:

```
pub trait Object {
    fn get(&self) -> i32;
    fn sub(&self, x: &dyn Object) -> Box<dyn Object>;
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Integer {
    val: i32,
}

impl Integer {
    fn new(val: i32) -> Box<dyn Object> {
        Box::new(Int { val })
    }
}

impl Object for Integer {
    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        self.val
    }

    fn sub(&self, rhs: &dyn Object) -> Box<dyn Object> {
        Integer::new(self.val - rhs.get())
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Int {
    val: i32,
}

impl Int {
    fn new(val: i32) -> Box<dyn Object> {
        Box::new(Int { val })
    }
}

impl Object for Int {
    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        self.val
    }

    fn sub(&self, rhs: &dyn Object) -> Box<dyn Object> {
        Int::new(self.val - rhs.get())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn Object>> = vec![];
    v.push(Integer::new(1));
    v.push(Int::new(2));
    v.push(v[0].sub(v[1].as_ref()));
    for o in &v {
        println!("{}", o.get());
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb2302bb4e336eec7ea96a7dfe5329ff)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can combine trait and provide a blank implementation, then use that in vector

```
trait TraitA {}
trait TraitB {}
trait CombinedTraitATraitB: TraitA + TraitB {}
impl<T> CombinedTraitATraitB for T where T: TraitA + TraitB  {}

let vector: Vec<Box<dyn CombinedTraitATraitB>> = vec![];
```